# boost::thread & member function

Tags: c++, boost, multithreading, unresolved-external

I've facing this problem when trying to use boost::thread:

unresolved external symbols:

```
public: __thiscall boost::thread::~thread(void)
public: __thiscall boost::thread::thread(void)
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told your linker to link with the boost threads library. Without info on compiler and platform, nobody can help you further.